# Convert paypal sandbox account into live account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am currently using PayPal Sandbox credentials to test my project.

Now I want to change sandbox environment to live enviroment and I am using NVP in c# .Net

```
NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();

IAPIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();

 profile.APIUsername = APIUserName;
 profile.APIPassword = APIPAssword;
 profile.APISignature = APISignature;
 **profile.Environment = "live";**
 caller.APIProfile = profile;
```

Anything else required to change or just changing "sandbox" to "live" will work

Regards,

Dharmesh Solanki

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the the environment, and you would need to update your API credentials to reflect that of your live account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

So basically I need to change 2 things to move sandbox environment into live environment.

1. Change SandBox Credentials into Live Credentials
2. Change profile.Environment = "live";

Anything else I need to change?

Also I believe based on **profile.Environment ** API end points will be changed automatically.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Correct the profile endpoint should be automatically changed when you change the environment.  That should be all that you need to change, other then setting your live account up to mimic your test one you were developer with, such as if you had IPN set up on the account and etc.